# Regex - everything except string

Tags: regex

I would like to replace every char that is not a string for a given char like `|` or `;` or whatever.
I have simple regex patern: `([a-zA-Z])\w+`

...and the problem is to replace everything except matches of that pattern.

Example: `qwerty 123456 ;,.'[]?/ asd`

Result: `qwerty|||||||||||||||||asd`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you try: `echo "qwerty 123456 ;,.'[]?/ asd" | perl -lpe 's/[\W\d]/|/g'` you will get:`qwerty|||||||||||||||||asd`. So you can use `[\W\d]` => All non-world plus digits

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter/match/replace in two Ways

First Variant:

```
[a-z0-9] // filter/match/replace everything that is included in the defined Character set
```

Second Variant:

```
[^a-z0-9] // filter/match/replace everything that is NOT included in the defined Character set
```

As you see, the only Difference is the `^`. `^` is the negation Operator within a Character Set.

Answer (score 0):

- You can negate the characters in your character set using `^`.
- `\w` needs to be omitted, because otherwise it will also try to match any word character
- The brackets are not necessary, since there is no need to group a single character set and you are not using a `backreference` to that capturing group

This results in the following regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

For this input:
`qwerty 123456 ;,.'[]?/ asd`
You want to match **all non-word** plus **digits**, so you can use `[\W\d]`

But since you want to replace them one-by-one not all them at once you no need to use quantifier `+`

Also you can use: build-in-character class if your **engine** or your **language** has them. For example:

```
[:alnum:]       all letters and digits
[:alpha:]       all letters
[:blank:]       all horizontal whitespace
[:cntrl:]       all control characters
[:digit:]       all digits
[:graph:]       all printable characters, not including space
[:lower:]       all lower case letters
[:print:]       all printable characters, including space
[:punct:]       all punctuation characters
[:space:]       all horizontal or vertical whitespace
[:upper:]       all upper case letters
[:xdigit:]      all hexadecimal digits
```

See a fest test with **Perl**

```
echo "qwerty 123456 ;,.'[]?/ asd" | perl -lpe 's/[[:cntrl:][:punct:]\d ]/|/g'
```

or:

```
echo "qwerty 123456 ;,.'[]?/ asd" | perl -lpe 's/[\W\d]/|/g'
```

has the same output:

```
qwerty|||||||||||||||||asd
```

---

NOTE:

For more detail you can see: [Regular Expression Reference: Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html)